# ItextSharp cannot extract texts with the character 'I'

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

The following function gets the text (in this case, employee number) in a PDF file using `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`.

```
private static string GetEmployeeNo(int cnt, iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader)
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(475, 730, 500, 750);
    RenderFilter[] filter = { new RegionTextRenderFilter(rect) };
    ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), filter);
    string employeeNo = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, cnt, strategy);
    return employeeNo;
}
```

The position of the text for employee number for every PDF file is fixed, so I can just have a `Rectangle` object that I can pass as a filter.
This works fine until the text I needed to extract contains 'I' (capital i). In this case, the function returns a null string.

I assume that this is because of the ambiguity between the capital i and the small letter L, both of which are rendered as 'I' in some font/typeface. Knowing this, I still can't find information/documentation about the issue.

If this is the case, how can I tell ITextSharp to extract texts based on, lets say, a specific font family. Or if this isn't a probable solution, at least, how can I tell ITextSharp to treat 'I' character as L instead of returning a null string?

Comment: iText *can* extract text with the character 'I' *in general*, but there may be *specific* PDF files that have some *specific* peculiarity that causes a problem with characters 'I'. Unless you share such a *specific* PDF, you will not get any answers. People will just assume that your allegation is false, because there is no reason whatsoever why iTextSharp would treat the character 'I' differently.